# Issue with Bind the Kendo Grid in asp.net

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid, telerik-grid

I have an issue with the Kendo UI Grid for ASP.net MVC, the grid populated successfull if the entity framework model have one table (order), but if I added the foreign table for it (order_summary) the grid not populate and shown empty

I used the following method to populate the grid

```
public ActionResult orders_Read([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
    {
        using (dbEntities _context = new dbEntities())
        {
            IQueryable<order> query = _context.order;
            return Json(query.ToDataSourceResult(request));
        }
    }
```

The view

```
.Read(read => read.Action("orders_Read", "Home"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your Network Tab, there you will see the error message for the request "orders_Read". You may have circular dependencies or similar which the serializer does not like.

You can easily avoid them by **not populating your entities directly, instead create a dto**. You can map that with [AutoMapper](https://automapper.org/).

Another option (not really nice in my opinion) would be, to return an anonymous type:

```
 IQueryable<order> query = _context.order.Select(t=>new { ... });
```